# Laravel 4 how to zip file

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-4

Any body please suggest me how to zip folder and download that zip file on laravel4.

I need to zip folder `/public/zipfolder/`

after zipped then automatic download `zipfolder.zip`

I install this package

https://github.com/codeless/ziparchiveex

and route to

```
public function show($id)
{
    //echo $id;
    # ZipArchive as usual:
    $zip = new ZipArchiveEx();
    //$zip->open('my.zip', ZIPARCHIVE::OVERWRITE);

    # Add whole directory including contents:
    $zip->addDir('/public/zipfolder/');

    # Only add the contents of the directory, but
    # not the directory-entry of "mydir" itself:
    //$zip->addDirContents('mydir');

    # Close archive (as usual):
    $zip->close();
}
```

and i got error below

> `ZipArchive::addEmptyDir()`: Invalid or unitialized `Zip` object

Comment: Show us what have you tried

Answer (score 1):

When you start a path with "/" the path becomes *absolute* and will cause PHP to look from the root of the server's file system.  Instead use `public_path()` to get the path on disk to `public`...

```
$zip->addDir(public_path().'/zipfolder/');
```

Answer (score 0):

This is code apply for you affter zipped then automatic download my.zip

```
public function show($id)
{
    //echo $id;
    # ZipArchive as usual:
    $zip = new ZipArchiveEx();
    $zip->open('my.zip', ZIPARCHIVE::OVERWRITE);

    # Add whole directory including contents:
    $zip->addDir('/public/zipfolder/');

    # Only add the contents of the directory, but
    # not the directory-entry of "mydir" itself:
    //$zip->addDirContents('mydir');

    # Close archive (as usual):
    $zip->close();

    // Stream the file to the client 
    header("Content-Type: application/zip"); 
    header("Content-Length: " . filesize('my.zip')); 
    header("Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=\"my.zip\""); 
    readfile('my.zip'); 

    unlink('my.zip');
}
```